# How do I check for the presence of a keyword in a Racket syntax?

Tags: racket

I want to check whether a keyword is present in a syntax object.
It's easy when the keyword is followed by an expression:

```
(syntax-parse #'(hello #:world "sunny")
  [(_ (~optional (~seq #:world <adjective>:str)))
   #'(string-append "Hello world! Today's weather is "
                    (~? <adjective> "unknown"))])
```

But if I want to check only for the presence of a keyword, I don't have a syntax binding to check anymore:

```
(syntax-parse #'(hello #:world)
  [(_ (~optional #:world))
   #:with maybe-world (if (attribute #:world) #'" world" #'"") ; doesn't work
   #'(string-append "Hello" maybe-world "!")])
```

How do I bind the presence of `#:world` to a syntax attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `~and` to bind a syntax to an attribute:

```
(syntax-parse #'(hello #:world)
  [(_ (~optional (~and world? #:world)))
   #:with maybe-world (if (attribute world?) #'" world" #'"")
   #'(string-append "Hello" maybe-world "!")])
```

---

From the doc [https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html?q=~and#(elem.*(pattern-link.*(~7eand._s)))](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html?q=~and#(elem._(pattern-link._(~7eand._s)))) :

```
One use for ~and-patterns is preserving a whole term (including its lexical
context, source location, etc) while also examining its structure.
Syntax classes are useful for the same purpose, but ~and can be lighter weight.
```

Comment: See also [1.2.5 More Keyword Arguments](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/More_Keyword_Arguments.html).